# Axon Framework: Handle only events published by the same JVM instance?

Tags: cqrs, axon

Hi Axon Framework community,

I'd like to have your opinion on how to solve the following problem properly.

**My Axon Test Setup**

- Two instances of the same Spring Boot application (using axon-spring-boot-starter 4.4 without Axon Server)
- Every instance publishes the same events on a regular interval
- Both instances are connected to the same EventSource (single SQL Server instance using JpaEventStorageEngine)
- Every instance is configured to use TrackingEventProcessors
- Every instances has the same event handlers registered

**What I want to achieve**

I'd like that events published by one instance are only handled by the very same instance

> If instance1 publishes eventX then only instance1 should handle eventX

**What I've tried so far**

- I can achieve the above scenario using SubscribingEventProcessor. Unfortunately this is not an option in my case, since we'd like to have the option to replay events for rebuilding / adding new query models.
- I could assign the event handlers of every instance to differed processing groups. Unfortunately this didn't worked. Maybe because every TrackingEventProcessors instance processes the same EventStream ? - not so sure about this though.
- I could implement a MessageHandlerInterceptor which only proceeds in case the event origin is from the same instance. This is what I implemented so far and which works properly:
  *MessageHandlerInterceptor*

```kotlin
class StackEventInterceptor(private val stackProperties: StackProperties) : MessageHandlerInterceptor<EventMessage<*>> {

    override fun handle(unitOfWork: UnitOfWork<out EventMessage<*>>?, interceptorChain: InterceptorChain?): Any? {
        val stackId = (unitOfWork?.message?.payload as SomeEvent).stackId
        if(stackId == stackProperties.id){
            interceptorChain?.proceed()
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Configuration
class AxonConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    fun configure(eventProcessingConfigurer: EventProcessingConfigurer, stackProperties: StackProperties) {
        val processingGroup = "processing-group-stack-${stackProperties.id}"
        eventProcessingConfigurer.byDefaultAssignTo(processingGroup)
        eventProcessingConfigurer.registerHandlerInterceptor(processingGroup) { StackEventInterceptor(stackProperties) }
    }
}
```

**Is there a better solution ?**

I have the impression that my current solution is properly not the best one, since ideally I'd like that only the event handlers which belongs to a certain instance are triggered by the TrackingEventProcessor instances.

How would you solve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting scenario you're having here @thowimmer.
My first hunch would be to say "use the `SubscribingEventProcessor` instead".
However, you pointed out that that's not an option in your setup.
I'd argue it's *very* valuable for others who're in the same scenario to know why that's not an option. So, maybe you can elaborate on that (to be honest, I am curious about that too).

Now for your problem case to ensure events are only handled within the same JVM.
Adding the origin to the events is definitely **a** step you can take, as this allows for a logical way to filter. "Does this event originate from `my.origin()`?" If not, you'd just ignore the event and be done with it, simple as that. There is another way to achieve this though, to which I'll come to in a bit.

The place to filter is however what you're looking for mostly I think. But first, I'd like to specify  *why* you need to filter in the first place. As you've noticed, the `TrackingEventProcessor` (TEP) streams events from a so called `StreamableMessageSource`. The `EventStore` is an implementation of such a `StreamableMessageSource`. As you are storing all events in the same store, well, it'll just stream everything to your TEPs. As your events are part of a single Event Stream, you are required to filter them at some stage. Using a `MessageHandlerInterceptor` would work, you could even go and write a `HandlerEnhacnerDefinition` allowing you to add additional behaviour to your Event Handling functions. However you put it though, with the current setup, filtering needs to be done somewhere. The `MessageHandlerInterceptor` is arguably the simplest place to do this at.

However, there is a different way of dealing with this. Why not segregate your Event Store, into two distinct instances for both applications? Apparently they *do not* have the need to read from one another, so why share the same Event Store at all? Without knowing further background of your domain, I'd guess you are essentially dealing with applications residing in distinct [bounded contexts](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html). *Very* shortly put, there is zero interest to share everything with both applications/contexts, you just share specifics portions of your domain language very consciously with one another.

Note that support for [multiple contexts](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/v/master/axon-server/administration/multi-context), using a single communication hub in the middle, is *exactly* what Axon Server can achieve for you. I am not here to say you cant configure this yourself though, I have done this in the past. But leaving that work to somebody or something else, freeing you from the need to configure infrastructure, that would be a massive timesaver.

Hope this helps you set the context a little of my thoughts on the matter @thowimmer.

Comment: Hi @Steven,

first of all many thanks your great support ! Axon is and outstanding team when it comes to supporting the community, building great tech and being respectful to each other - kudos !

A little more background to my problem:
We are using blue/green deployments in an active/passive setup.
This means that during a deployment an event originated by a working node could be handled by a potentially broken node. Each of both nodes have a dedicated DB instance which are mirrored, so that we can patch DB instances with zero downtime.

Comment: To your suggestions:
1) Subscribing vs Tracking: We'd like to replay events to add/rebuild query models later. (edited my question)
2) Segregate EventStore: I've actually thought about that but wanted to evaluate other options first - Nevertheless it's probably the way to go as outlined by you.
3) Different bounded contexts: In fact it's the very same app, but just different instances for operational purposes.
4) Axon Server: On the mid term we will switch probably to Axon Server. I will further evaluate its options :-)

Comment: First of, thanks for the compliment! We strive to provide thorough and clear explanation to any questions on any of the Axon products, so it is always pleasant to hear the experience is as such. :-)

Comment: About your scenario, gotcha! If you're talking about a blue-green deployment strategy, the requirements are slightly different of course. What is the exact issue you are trying to mitigate by segregating the events from the blue and green app?

Comment: I want to avoid, that during a deployment the blue instance (old version) publishes events to the green instance (new version).
There are actually several reasons for it:
Main) Consumers of the old version (blue) should not be affected by changes of the new, possible broken, version (green) 
Other) Our EventHandlers communicate with further system components which would lead to commands being published on the green instance - this instance might be broken, due to misconfiguration or incompatible code changes

-> Bottom line: blue&green must be isolated to achieve zero downtime deployments

Comment: Using the same event store for both the blue and green instance is reasonable and logical. I assume you are segregating the database solution for your query models and tokens however? In a Blue-Green deployment you are essentially building up the new instance. Thus, having it handle events to warm up your Query Models is reasonable. Having it publish events would typically _not_ occur though, unless you are publish events when handling events(?).

Comment: I'd argue the Event Handling Components which communicate with other (external/3rd party) systems would ideally not start yet. Only once the green system has been brought up to speed, thus it's in a usable state for you rend users, would you start handling events on those components to trigger your external services (potentially sagas as well).

Comment: Yes this is an other option -> register evenhandlers once everything is ready & in a healthy state. This would of course be possible but would require some additional step during deployments which I would like to avoid to reduce deployment complexity. I will try out the application level approach: https://github.com/thowimmer/axon-eventhandling-same-instance - its easy to understand and solves our problem. I'm not yet sure whether the PID approach is the best one though, since we might loose events when PID change (e.g. during respawning/switching instances)... I will keep you up to date ;-)

Comment: Awesome, great work thus far @thowimmer. This Q&A holds a lot of helpful info for others already; let's keep that up!

Answer (score 0):

**Sumup:**

Using the same EventStore for both instances is probably no an ideal setup in case we want to use the capabilities of the `TrackingEventProcessor`.

Options to solve it:

- Dedicated (not mirrored) DB instance for each application instance.
- Using [multiple contexts](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/v/master/axon-server/administration/multi-context) using AxonServer.

If we decide to solve the problem on application level filtering using `MessageHandlerInterceptor` is the most simplest solution.

Thanks @Steven for exchanging ideas.

---

EDIT:

Solution on application level using `CorrelationDataProvider` & `MessageHandlerInterceptor` by filtering out events not originated in same process.

*AxonConfiguration.kt*

```kotlin
const val METADATA_KEY_PROCESS_ID = "pid"
const val PROCESSING_GROUP_PREFIX = "processing-group-pid"

@Configuration
class AxonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun processIdCorrelationDataProvider() = ProcessIdCorrelationDataProvider()

    @Autowired
    fun configureProcessIdEventHandlerInterceptor(eventProcessingConfigurer: EventProcessingConfigurer) {
        val processingGroup = "$PROCESSING_GROUP_PREFIX-${ApplicationPid()}"
        eventProcessingConfigurer.byDefaultAssignTo(processingGroup)
        eventProcessingConfigurer.registerHandlerInterceptor(processingGroup) { ProcessIdEventHandlerInterceptor() }
    }
}

class ProcessIdCorrelationDataProvider() : CorrelationDataProvider {
    override fun correlationDataFor(message: Message<*>?): MutableMap<String, *> {
        return mutableMapOf(METADATA_KEY_PROCESS_ID to ApplicationPid().toString())
    }
}

class ProcessIdEventHandlerInterceptor : MessageHandlerInterceptor<EventMessage<*>> {
    override fun handle(unitOfWork: UnitOfWork<out EventMessage<*>>?, interceptorChain: InterceptorChain?) {
        val currentPid = ApplicationPid().toString()
        val originPid = unitOfWork?.message?.metaData?.get(METADATA_KEY_PROCESS_ID)
        if(currentPid == originPid){
            interceptorChain?.proceed()
        }
    }
}
```

See full demo project on [GitHub](https://github.com/thowimmer/axon-eventhandling-same-instance)